# Trying to make ListView display new information using CursorAdapter

Tags: java, android, sqlite, listview

I am a new Android programmer. I am entering data into an SQLite database, and I want my ListView to then refresh and show the information that I have just added to the database. The ListView is below the add button. The logcat error shows a NullPointerException.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/LinearLayout6"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.34"
            android:text="Registration No:"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/vehicle_reg"
            android:layout_width="175dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="10"
            />
          <requestFocus />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/LinearLayout7"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.43"
            android:text="Mileage:"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/vehicle_mileage"
            android:layout_width="114dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.29"
            android:ems="10" >


        </EditText>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/LinearLayout8"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="36dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.51"
            android:text="Budget Amount:"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/vehicle_budget"
            android:layout_width="167dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.13"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="numberDecimal" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/LinearLayout9"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.37"
            android:text="Tank Capacity: "
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/vehicle_capacity"
            android:layout_width="172dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="10" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
           android:id="@+id/LinearLayout10"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/add_button_vehicle"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Add Vehicle" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/LinearLayout11"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.43"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/vehicleList_reg"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1" >
        </ListView>

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

---

```
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.example.budgetfuel.databasemodel.Car;
import com.example.budgetfuel.databasemodel.DBhelper;
import com.example.budgetfuel.databasemodel.DatabaseHelper;
import com.example.budgetfuel.databasemodel.SQLController;

public class VehicleSetup extends FragmentActivity {

    Button addvehicle;
    ListView lv;
    SQLController dbcon;
    Button btnAdd;
    EditText reg, milge, cap, budgt;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.fragment_settings);

        // get action bar
        ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();

        // Enabling Up / Back navigation
        actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        dbcon = new SQLController(this);
        dbcon.open();
        addvehicle = (Button) findViewById(R.id.add_button_vehicle);
        lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listViewVehicles);
        reg = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.vehicle_reg);
        milge = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.vehicle_mileage);
        cap = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.vehicle_budget);
        budgt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.vehicle_capacity);



        // Attach The Data From DataBase Into ListView Using Crusor Adapter
        Cursor cursor = dbcon.readData();
        String[] from = new String[] {DBhelper.VEHICLE_ID,DBhelper.VEHICLE_REG, DBhelper.VEHICLE_BUDGET, DBhelper.VEHICLE_CAPACITY };

        int[] to = new int[] { R.id.vehicle_id, R.id.vehicle_reg, R.id.vehicle_mileage, R.id.vehicle_budget,
                R.id.vehicle_capacity };
        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")

        SimpleCursorAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(
                VehicleSetup.this, R.layout.view_car_entry, cursor, from, to);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        lv.setAdapter(adapter);
//      
        addvehicle.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                String registration = reg.getText().toString();
                int mileage = Integer.parseInt(milge.getText().toString());
                int capacity = Integer.parseInt(cap.getText().toString());
                double budget = Double.parseDouble(budgt.getText().toString());
                dbcon.insertData(registration, mileage, budget, capacity);

                reg.setText("");
                milge.setText("");
                cap.setText("");
                budgt.setText("");


            }
        });



    }
```

Answer (score 0):

try to put `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();` after `lv.setAdapter(adapter);`

Comment: Tried this it is still giving me a Fatal Exception error in the log cat

Comment: could you update your question with the error log? its easier for me to see

Comment: 05-10 02:43:54.447: E/AndroidRuntime(5451): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-10 02:43:54.447: E/AndroidRuntime(5451): Process: com.example.budgetfuel, PID: 5451
05-10 02:43:54.447: E/AndroidRuntime(5451): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.budgetfuel/com.example.budgetfuel.VehicleSetup}: java.lang.NullPointerException
05-10 02:43:54.447: E/AndroidRuntime(5451):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)
05-10 02:43:54.447: E/AndroidRuntime(5451):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:

Comment: I guess you need to make sure that every variable is not giving null value. cause from the error log it seem that one of your variable should be giving null value. keep look on the log it might show you which line of the java file causing the trouble.